# What are the things missing in Owin/Katana which is available in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

I am looking to build a small ASP.NET application using WebAPI and a html front-end, on .NET 4.0. I need to support authentication, authorization, data access (EF), logging / tracing. It can be an intranet/internet application, so it should support load balancing / clustering.
I am sure if I just go with ASP.NET and IIS I will get all these features. However I like OWINs idea of independent async modules and its goal of being high performance hosting environment. But how much of OWIN/ KATANA is matured and what functionalities are still missing/buggy?

Comment: I don't know about OWIN/ KATANA but I advice you to take a look at MVC4 [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) it's filled with features and I think it will do what ever you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of `Owin`/`Katana` is to build a light weight server with only the function we need. Your question is better to be "What are things missing in `Owin/Katana`, which is available in IIS?"

The short answer is, IIS is a full-blown server. Many of the websites we developed only requires a small fraction of all its functions. It is like shipping a bag of grocery using an 18 wheeler.

If you look at `Katana`, all functions are modular. Say, if I need WebAPI, I can add in that function. When CORS is needed, I will extend `appBuilder` to the related functions. So in a sense, we have a fully customizable server. Since all functions can be added in, I would say nothing is missing.

Another thing to mention is that an installation of IIS would require you to run a Windows Server. If you are on a Mac or not a server version of Windows, you can host your website on `Katana` or any other `OWIN` implementation.